# How would you prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}= \frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, induction

And another task from an old exam:

> Prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}= \frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}$$
>
> for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I smell proof by induction but I don't know how to do the start. I know how an induction proof is made up and done but I cannot really apply it on this task. Firstly, the sum symbol seems annoying for me, very annoying.

But I did the start by putting $k=1$ on the left side and $n=1$ on the right side:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{1}\frac{1}{(1+1)!} = \frac{(1+1)!-1}{(1+1)!}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{1}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

which is true.

So if it works for one $n$, it should work for $n+1$ as well (here is another problem, shall I concentrate on the left or the right side..?!).

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}= \frac{(n+2)!-1}{(n+2)!}$$

Hmm and from this point, also when it starts getting exciting, I didn't feel well continuing because... yeah the sum symbol is very confusing here.

Okay, maybe a little change that might look it a bit shorter / more nice:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k! \cdot (k+2)}= 1 - \frac{1}{(n+2)!}$$

Did I do it correctly till here at all? Is my approach of using induction correct...?

Comment: Write $k = (k+1) - 1$ in the numerator. Telescope.

Comment: If you'd like to prove it by induction, what you'd like to show is $\sum^{n+1}_{k=1}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{(n+2)!-1}{(n+2)!}$

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(k+1)-1}{(k+1)!} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} -\frac{1}{k!}$$
But what then?

Comment: $$\frac{(k+1)-1}{(k+1)!} = \frac{k+1}{(k+1)!} - \frac{1}{(k+1)!} = \frac{1}{k!} - \frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$

Comment: Ahhh alright but how can someone get that idea doing this I DONT UNDERSTAND how you can get to this idea in an exam when you have some minutes for task only.. :O very desperate right now. And tyvm you help me with many asks today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $k=(k+1)-1$ and $(k+1)!=(k+1)\cdot k!$ we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{(k+1)!} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(k+1)!} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}}$$
i.e. a telescopic sum.

Answer (score 1):

It is always time for an overkill. Since $$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}=\frac{e^{x}\Gamma\left(n+2,x\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}
 $$ where $\Gamma\left(a,b\right)
 $ is the [incomplete Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html), follows that $$\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}=\frac{e^{x}\Gamma\left(n+2,x\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!x}-\frac{1}{x}-1
 $$ so taking the derivative $$\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{\left(k-1\right)x^{k-2}}{k!}=\frac{e^{x}\left(x-1\right)\Gamma\left(n+2,x\right)-x^{n+2}}{\left(n+1\right)!x^{2}}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}
 $$ and the result follows taking $x=1
 $ $$\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{\left(k-1\right)}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{\left(k+1\right)!}=\color{red}{1-\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!}}.$$