# A series involving Gamma function: $\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{kx^k}{\Gamma(k+1+x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, gamma-function

From this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4890225/1231520), it implicitly becomes evident that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{kn^k}{(k+n)!} =\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$$

holds for any integer $n$.

I **guess** that the following general formula holds for any $x>0$:

$$\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{kx^k}{\Gamma(k+1+x)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}}.$$

I could not find the above identity in the literature of the Gamma function. In fact, known expansions of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}$ are complex.

For $x=1$, see this related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1917115/1231520).

Could you prove the guess?

Comment: This is a known result... (according to Maple).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have to prove
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k x^k \Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(k+1+x)} = 1 .
$$
Recall the Beta function
$$
\int_0^1 t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1}\;dt = B(a,b) = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}
$$
The term in our sum is
$$
\frac{k x^k \Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(k+1+x)} = \frac{x^k B(k+1,x)}{(k-1)!}
$$
since $\Gamma(k+1) = k\Gamma(k)$ and $\Gamma(k) = (k-1)!$.
Thus
$$
\frac{k x^k \Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(k+1+x)} 
= \frac{x^k}{(k-1)!}\int_0^1 t^{x-1} (1-t)^k\;dt
$$
Let's interchange sum and integral [needs justification] to compute
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k x^k \Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(k+1+x)}
= \int_0^1 t^{x-1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-t)^k \frac{x^k}{(k-1)!}\;dt
\\
= \int_0^1 t^{x-1} (1-t) x e^{x(1-t)}\;dt =
t^x e^{x(1-t)}\big|_{t=0}^1= 1 .
$$

Comment: Using a similar approach, you could even show that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{kx^k}{\Gamma(k+1+x)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma (x)}-\frac{x^{n+1}}{\Gamma (n+x+1)}$$